# How can one improve this code with a loop so that it is much shorter and efficient?

Tags: vb.net, loops

Visual Basic

The program asks the user for an item, its price and how many ordered items of the same and then saves it to the appropriate variable.
But how could it be improved with a loop?

Please show me how can I improve my code.

```
   'Asking user for item name, price of items, amount ordered, takeout? and age.

   'Item 1
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the item.")
    item1 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of " & item1 & ".")
    Console.Write("£")
    priceOfItem1 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ordered.")
    amountOrdered1 = Console.ReadLine()

    'Item 2
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the item.")
    item2 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of " & item2 & ".")
    Console.Write("£")
    priceOfItem2 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ordered.")
    amountOrdered2 = Console.ReadLine()

    'Item 3
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the item.")
    item3 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of the item.")
    Console.Write("£")
    priceOfItem3 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ordered.")
    amountOrdered3 = Console.ReadLine()

    'Item 4
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the item.")
    item4 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of the item.")
    Console.Write("£")
    priceOfItem4 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ordered.")
    amountOrdered4 = Console.ReadLine()

    'Item 5
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the item.")
    item5 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of the item.")
    Console.Write("£")
    priceOfItem5 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ordered.")
    amountOrdered5 = Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: This is really basic. Have you tried anything?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Is this a program you wrote, did you read it in a book, or what? Do you know what a loop is? You tried one and it gave an error message? What programming language are you using?

Comment: This is Visual Basic, folks. That was in the original title, but it was edited out.

Comment: I am stuck on how to make the code more efficient by using loops so the code doesn't have to have a lot of repeated code. This is part of a program I wrote. I didn't include the rest. I do know what a loop is. The code above works but as I said I want to make the code better. The programming langauge I am using is Visual Basic.

Comment: That's about all the questions so far asked about my question, answered.

Comment: Loops don't necessarily make code more efficient - resources/memory is consumed by the machinery of the looping itself.  However looping can make code more concise, comprehensible, and easily alterable in some ways.  So my question is: Are you really looking to improve efficiency of the code, or do you want it to be more easily readable?

Comment: At this stage in time, I am looking for it to be more easily readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the VB code you need to shorten your code and make it more elegant:

```
Dim priceOfItem(4) As Int32
Dim amountOrdered(4) As Int32
Dim items(4) As String

For i As Int32 = 0 To 4
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the item.")
   items(i) = Console.ReadLine()
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of the item.")
   Console.Write("£")
   priceOfItem(i) = Console.ReadLine()
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ordered.")
   amountOrdered(i) = Console.ReadLine()
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what language you are using, but a general structure is the following, you can use arrays instead of variables.

```
int priceOfItem[5], amountOrdered[5];
String item[5];
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the item.")
   item[i] = Console.ReadLine()
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price of the item.")
   Console.Write("£")
   priceOfItem[i] = Console.ReadLine()
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ordered.")
   amountOrdered[i] = Console.ReadLine()
}
```

Comment: I am using visual basic so could you please change your answer to suit the language. That would be much appreciated.